# Accessing WHERE clause conditions in foreign data wrapper

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I am exposing data from a key/value store through a set of FDW tables. It's all working fine except that Postgres is frequently forced to scan an entire table when I only need a small subset.

For example:

> SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id='WLW001';

Unless I add LIMIT 1 to the end, it will search through all person rows.

In my key/value store, I just need to pass "WLW001" through as part of the key to find the right record directly.

In other words, I need to find the WHERE clause conditions to optimize my queries into the key/value store. I have looked through many of the example FDW's and and documentation, and cannot find anything that describes the use of the RelOptInfo or scan_clauses list or helper functions to obtain this information.

Also, if the SELECT statement contains parameter markers, it appears that I need to substitute the value for the marker. Where do I find the value?

Comment: Which key/value store data wrapper are you using? Some data wrappers can take WHERE conditions to be processed on the remote server so as to reduce the number of rows sent. If it is a fdw for a file store, then it will likely retrieve the whole file and scan it entirely; an alternative can be creating your own stored procedures to retrieve the data with the logic that suits your needs, through `plperlu`.

Comment: The key/value store is our own, used to access terabytes of data. The key is multi-part. So if I can plug the WHERE conditions into the key, I can go directly to the records of interest.

Comment: what format is the datastore? Which foreign data wrappers are you using?

Comment: The datastore is our own creation with a key/value API. I'm writing the FDW myself to access this data through Postgres. When the SQL WHERE clause says "person_id='WLW001'" I can plug 'WLW001' into the key in my API and quickly find the record. My question is about asking Postgres for the column name (person_id) and value (WLW001) from within the FDW code that I'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed in the mysql_fdw project (https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) in a file named deparse.c. PostgreSQL will parse a query and turn it into individual table queries. Then it will call the FDW callbacks for each different table, each with its own set of WHERE conditions. It is possible to walk a tree in the PostgreSQL data structures to obtain the exact conditions it is searching for within that table.